# Jquery replace parent with first child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to replace a dom parent with its first child and deleting all other children. It's not working. I got error: "Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy"

```
$("#over1").replaceWith($(this).children()[0]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` isn't referencing the #over1 element. Instead you should do:

```
$("#over1").replaceWith(function() { return $(':first', this); });
```